# Angular 7 SSR got ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, server-side-rendering

I am using Angular 7 in my project and I want to add SSR (Server Side Rendering) to my project.
I using command

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject matngular
```

So they adding a bunch of files.
Then I am continuing with command

```
npm run build:ssr
```

And the build was succeded. So I start serving that dist folder by using command

```
npm run serve:ssr
```

So I got error like below

```
D:\git-workspace\the-seagate-suite\seagate-web\dist\server.js:205940
'function' === typeof document.createEvent ? function CustomEvent (type, params) {
                  ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
at Object.eventmap (D:\git-workspace\the-seagate-suite\seagate-web\dist\server.js:205940:23)
at __webpack_require__ (D:\git-workspace\the-seagate-suite\seagate-web\dist\server.js:20:30)
at Object.NativeCustomEvent (D:\git-workspace\the-seagate-suite\seagate-web\dist\server.js:205812:19)
at __webpack_require__ (D:\git-workspace\the-seagate-suite\seagate-web\dist\server.js:20:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\git-workspace\the-seagate-suite\seagate-web\dist\server.js:205097:17)
at __webpack_require__ (D:\git-workspace\the-seagate-suite\seagate-web\dist\server.js:20:30)
at Module.<anonymous> (D:\git-workspace\the-seagate-suite\seagate-web\dist\server.js:204339:65)
at __webpack_require__ (D:\git-workspace\the-seagate-suite\seagate-web\dist\server.js:20:30)
at Object.ng2-dragula (D:\git-workspace\the-seagate-suite\seagate-web\dist\server.js:156920:18)
at __webpack_require__ (D:\git-workspace\the-seagate-suite\seagate-web\dist\server.js:132440:30)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! the-seagate-suite@1.0.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/server` 
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the the-seagate-suite@1.0.0 serve:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11- 
20T07_04_53_246Z-debug.log
```

I already tried Stackoverflow's solutions accepted answers. But none was working for me.
My Angular project version is `7.3.6` and typeScript is `3.2.4`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Adam,

as Angular documentation states:

> Because a Universal app doesn't execute in the browser, some of the
> browser APIs and capabilities may be missing on the server.
>
> For example, server-side applications can't reference browser-only
> global objects such as window, document, navigator, or location.
>
> Angular provides some injectable abstractions over these objects, such
> as Location or DOCUMENT; it may substitute adequately for these APIs.
> If Angular doesn't provide it, it's possible to write new abstractions
> that delegate to the browser APIs while in the browser and to an
> alternative implementation while on the server (aka shimming).

You can try inject a Document instance via Angular Dependency Injection in the constructor of your component or service:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
```

Comment: Any tips on how to inject this "fake" document into the global scope so imported JS libraries like bootstrap com use it? Thank you.